# How to replace a (ring) for a in Python?

Tags: python, str-replace

I have a list with some thousands strings. Some strings have `&` that should be replaced by `and` some strings have `%` that should be replaced for  and so on. There are many rules.

There are some strings with this special character [a(ring)](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/capital-letter-a-ring-uppercase-ascii-code-134.html) that should be replaced by `a` lower case.

I am using the follow code:

```
brnd = 'Acne Studios Blå Konst'
print(brnd.lower().replace(' ','-').replace('.','').replace('%','').replace('\134','a'))

returns acne-studios-blå-konst
desired acne-studios-bla-konst
```

The a(ring) is still there. What am I missing here?
Python 2.7.12

Comment: What version of Python are you using? 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: the version is 2.7.12

Comment: Why `replace('\134', 'a')` instead of `replace('å', 'a')`?

Comment: Are you declaring a string encoding?

Comment: If I use directly I get SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file ...

Comment: no I am not declaring a string encode

Comment: You should probably do that if you intend to use unicode strings in Python 2.

Comment: @zwitterion do you want to remove replace all accented characters?

Comment: Now I am using # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- at the begging of the page... and is not working

Comment: The script already has `brnd = 'Acne Studios Blå Konst'`.  I don't see how `replace('å', 'a')` could cause problems.

Comment: @zwitterion also, if you are having problem with unicode vs ascii, definitely switch to Python3, everything has been harmonized

Comment: also, `\xc3` is 195 in decimal, not 134 like you have used

Comment: What is the default encoding - `sys.stdin.encoding`?

Comment: [latin small letter a with ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85#On_computers) - looks like that character is 229 decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **unicodedata** module.

**Demo:**

```
import unicodedata
brnd = 'Acne Studios Blå Konst'
print unicodedata.normalize('NFD', unicode(brnd, 'utf-8')).encode('ascii', 'ignore').lower().replace(' ','-')
```

**Output:**

```
acne-studios-bla-konst
```

Comment: Hy Rakesh this what I am getting after copy your code: `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file /home/ila/vhosts/crawler/bucky.py on line 6`. Line 6 is where a have the sentence `Acne Studios ...`